# fill one iframe div contents with another iframes information

Tags: php, html, dom

I am creating an invoicing system using php and HTML.

What I'm trying to achieve is communication from one iframe (details) form to another iframe (invoice) html page so that as the details form is filled in, the invoice reflects the changes.

I don't really want to have to submit the details part or refresh the invoice page at each change. Can anyone point me in the correct direction or advise me on the best course of action?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: don't use iframes there is almost always a better option

Comment: That's helpful (not!), how about suggesting an option?

Comment: insufficient information, to do more than point out the flaws

Comment: Thanks anyway, but not helpful

Comment: pointing out flaws is always helpful.

Comment: @hakre Not if it doesn't even suggest which direction to take. I really don't mind flaws being pointed out, but constructive criticism is always better than just pointing out a 'flaw'. For example, what is the flaw in using iframes? I might know, you might know, but someone who is just starting wouldn't have a clue!

Comment: There can be many issues with iframes. Security, Flow-Control, Sessions etc.. As you would need to use javascript anyway, you could consider to use AJAX requests instead and manipulate the DOM on the fly. That would for example prevent your from actually *needing* iframes. And as Security is a complex topic, you can't expect a book in a comment or answer to explain this to you. The comments most often are just pointing out the flaw and that's as most contructive as it can get on this website. Hence a comment, there is not much that could be improved with it IMHO.

Comment: That is a good answer. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) API.

This API allows iframes to communicate and exchange data. You use the `postMessage` method on the iframe's contentWindow attribute on the sending end, and register a "message" event listener on the receiving end. The mozilla page explains this all with example code.